# JasperExportManager only exporting 100 of 152 pages to PDF

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I am using JasperExportManager to export a JasperPrint report which contains 152 pages (confirmed by calling `JasperPrint#getPageCount()`) to a PDF. However the PDF contains only the first 100 pages.

I cannot find a method that indicates that the `JasperExportManager#exportReportToPdf(JasperPrint print, OutputStream os)` method should be "paged" in some manner. Can anyone shed some light on how to make sure the entire report is printed/exported?

Here is the code I am using...

```
Map args = new HashMap();

if (null != tResult){
  l.debug("Task Result is not Null");
  JasperResult jResult = tResult.getReport();
  if(null != jResult){
    JasperPrint jPrint = jResult.getJasperPrint();
    l.debug("Total Pages: " + jResult.getPageCount());

    l.debug("Jasper Result is not Null");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    String fileName = filePrefix + sdf.format(date) + ".pdf";
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation + fileName));
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jResult.getJasperPrint(), os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
  }
}
```

For clarity, the tResult is an object created by the product I am using that contains a JasperResult, which is a wrapper around a JasperPrint object. `JasperResult#getJasperPrint()` returns the `JasperPrint` object containing the report.

Comment: No error or anything when exporting to PDF? I can assure you that Jasper can definitely create more than 100 pages in a PDF ... Is there actually information missing in the resulting PDF? Or do you just assume that there should be more pages? And how exactly is that `getPageCount()` calculating the number of pages?

Comment: No error. There are indeed not pages. I can export the same report through this products UI and see all 152 pages. When comparing that result with mine, they are identical through 100 pages. That's where my report ends. I have also used the CSV exporter and again... 100 pages.

Comment: Edit: There are indeed `more` pages... :)